# Print variable containing command

Tags: linux, bash, variables, echo

Can somebody tell me how to print variable and not executing it in bash? I mean:

```
bash@bash $ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo $1

bash@bash $ ./script.sh "`date`"
Sat Sep 20 18:42:19 CEST 2014
```

I don't want to get:

```
Sat Sep 20 18:35:37 CEST 2014
```

I want to get output:

```
date
```

I'm interested in how to prevent executing sent commands to script.

Comment: Replace your back ticks with single quotes.

Comment: wrap with single quotes

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i made a mistake. I want to get  "echo date"

Comment: Then use single quotes on the first and double quotes on the second line.

Comment: [Don't do that.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to prevent code from being injected into your script. The problem with `echo $1` is that the contents of `$1` are being evaluated by the shell. In order to avoid that, you need to wrap `$1` in double quotes in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
```

Testing it out:

```
$ ./script.sh '`date`'
`date`
```

The problem in your question is that you are using double quotes around `"date"`, so the expansion has occurred before your script is run. You can use `set -x` to see the difference:

```
$ set -x
$ ./script '`date`'
+ ./script '`date`' 
`date`
$ ./script "`date`"
++ date                                   # date is being run
+ ./script 'Sat Sep 20 18:01:32 BST 2014' # result is passed to your script
Sat Sep 20 18:01:32 BST 2014
```

There is nothing you can do about this.

I think the following section of my original answer is still relevant, so I'll leave it in.

### Different types of quotes in bash

Backticks (which you have used in your question) are an old-fashioned way of capturing the output of executing a command. The more modern syntax is `$( )`, so if you wanted to store the current date in a variable you could do `d=$(date)`. Single quotes are used for literal strings, so `echo '$d'` would output `$d`, not the value of the variable. Variables inside double quotes are expanded, so `echo "$d"` would output the value of the variable `$d`. It is always a good idea to wrap your variables in double quotes to prevent [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [glob expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns).

Comment: Hi Tom, It could be unclear.Sorry, All I want to get is not executing commands but print it. You wrote "variable1=date". But what about when somebody pass to variable1 string \``date`\` ?

Comment: Sorry, last comment was not properly showed. string \``date\``

Comment: I hope that now it will be clear. I'm interested in how to prevent executing sent commands to script.

Comment: "The problem in your question is that you are using double quotes around "date", so the expansion has occurred before your script is run. You can use set -x to see the difference:" Thank you very much, now I see a difference! :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the backticks from **var1** with single quotes:

```sh
var1='date'
var2="echo $var1"
echo $var2
```

Comment: Your second line is bogus.